# LED flashlight on xperia Z5

Tags: android, surfaceview, flashlight, sony-xperia

I am using following code to turn LED flashlight on and off:

```
public Flashlight(SurfaceView preview, Context context){
        this.preview = preview;
        this.context = context;
        mHolder = preview.getHolder(); //mHolder is surfaceHolder
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            params = mCamera.getParameters();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

            //AUTOFOCUS LASER FIX ON LG G3
            List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (focusModes.contains(params.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY)) {
                params.setFocusMode(params.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY);
            }
            else{
                if (focusModes.contains(params.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED))
                    params.setFocusMode(params.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED);
            }
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
            cameraOpened = true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            cameraOpened = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void turnOnFlashlight(){
        flashlightOn = true;
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }
    private void turnOffFlashlight(){
        flashlightOn = false;
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }
```

It works great on most phones but I cant get it working on xperia Z5. I dont have Z5 for testing so I only know it from user response. So I would like to ask if there is any other (preferably working) way to turn on flashlight on Xperia Z5.

Thanks in forward

Comment: try adding ```mCamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));```, that's what i had to add for some devices. I don't know if your ```setPreviewDisplay``` does already do something similar though (EDIT: okay, without the actual device for testing that is far fetched, sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment, I found there to be 3 steps of making the flash appear (seems to be working on all devices so far)

```
cam.setParameters(p); // will trigger flash on most devices
// Needed for some devices.
cam.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));
// Needed for some more devices.
cam.startPreview();
```

Since you did 2 of those, try adding the PreviewTexture and it should work. The whole code of a working flashlight can be found here at [Flashlight Widget](https://github.com/bleeding182/minimalist-flashlight/blob/master/app/src/main/java/at/bleeding182/flashlight/FlashlightService.java)